# Is it possible to create a color fade for an individual cell in Google Apps Scripts for Google Sheets?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

So, say that if it's the most recent, i.e., the timestamp in this cell, is like 5 minutes ago, then it's dark green, but then if it's 30 minutes ago it's light green, and it fades to white after two hours.

The cell in question is governed by the below script:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  //e.source.toast("Entry");
  //console.log(JSON.stringify(e));
  const sh=e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName()=="Sheet1" && e.range.columnStart==2 && e.value) {
    e.range.offset(0,1).setValue(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(),Session.getScriptTimeZone(),"MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss"));
  }
  if(sh.getName()=="Sheet1" && e.range.columnStart==4 && e.value) {
    e.range.offset(0,1).setValue(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(),Session.getScriptTimeZone(),"MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss"));
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the timestamp changed by?

Comment: @Tanaike, this is what produces the timestamp for said cell: `function onEdit(e) {
  //e.source.toast("Entry");
  //console.log(JSON.stringify(e));
  const sh=e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName()=="Sheet1" && e.range.columnStart==2 && e.value) {
    e.range.offset(0,1).setValue(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(),Session.getScriptTimeZone(),"MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss"));
  }
  if(sh.getName()=="Sheet1" && e.range.columnStart==4 && e.value) {
    e.range.offset(0,1).setValue(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(),Session.getScriptTimeZone(),"MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss"));
  }
}`

Comment: Thank you for replying. In your situation, when the time stamp is less than 30 minutes and it is from just time to less than 2 hour later, what do you want to do? And, unfortunately, the values of time stamp cannot be checked with the real time. So in this case, I think that it might be required to run the script using the time-driven trigger. How about this? By the way, when you post the script, can you add it to your question? Because when the script is posted to the comment, it is difficult to see it.

Comment: @Tanaike, that works. What do you mean, specifically?

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunaetly, I cannot understand about `What do you mean, specifically?`. Can I ask you about the deatil of it?

Comment: What is your suggestion?

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill again. In your situation, I thought that the values of time stamp are required to be checked. In this case, how do you want to check them? For example, do you want to regularly check the values? Or for example, when the Spreadsheet is opened, do you want to check the values?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222997/discussion-between-loie-benedicte-and-tanaike).

Comment: Does your sheet contain several timestamps? Do you want to update regularaly the color of all the contained timestamps?

Comment: @ziganotschka, yes, multiple timestamps, update regularly across a color spectrum from white to green from 2hr to > 0min ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You can create the following function and set it on [time-driven trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#time-driven_triggers):

```js
function bindMeOnTimeDrivenTrigger(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("XXXXX").getSheetByName("Sheet1");  
  var stampContainingColumns = [3,5];
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var stamps = [sheet.getRange(1, stampContainingColumns[0], lastRow, 1).getValues().flat(), sheet.getRange(1, stampContainingColumns[1], lastRow, 1).getValues().flat()];
  var now = new Date().getTime();
  var fiveMin = 5*60*1000;
  var thirtyMin = 30*60*1000;
  var twoHours = 120*60*1000;
  for(var i =0; i < stamps.length; i++){
    for(var j =0; j < stamps[0].length; j++){
      if((typeof stamps[i][j]) == "object"){
        if(stamps[i][j].getTime()+twoHours < now){
          sheet.getRange(j+1, stampContainingColumns[i]).setBackground("white");
        }
        else if(stamps[i][j].getTime()+thirtyMin < now){
          sheet.getRange(j+1, stampContainingColumns[i]).setBackground("lightgreen");
        }
        else if(stamps[i][j].getTime()+fiveMin < now){
          sheet.getRange(j+1, stampContainingColumns[i]).setBackground("darkgreen");
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Of course you can incorporate more different shades and time ranges - you will need to implement in this case more different `else` statements.

Given that it is critical for you to check the timestamp every 5 minutes, it makes sense to set the time-driven trigger to execute every 5 minutes, however keep in mind the [Apps Script quotas](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas) that have a `Triggers total runtime per day` limit.

Comment: I tried to do a gradient across 5 minute intervals, but nothing: https://www.pastiebin.com/5f87aca7552bb Hex values not allowed...?

Comment: Triggers total runtime 90 min / day... So, at 10 minute check ups this would do what per day?

Comment: This is what I'm doing now: https://pastebin.com/BHFJCYQb

Comment: The method `setBackground(color)` accepts any values in Css notation (so also hex values) as you can read [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setbackgroundcolor). So your problem  must lie somewhere else. Implement some logs in every conditional statement to see if one is entered at all, and if it is the correct one.